# What does the dir_fd argument of os.fwalk() do?

Tags: python, python-os

If I assign an integer to the `dir_fd` argument of `os.fwalk()`, a fourth value ist added to each of the tuples generated by `list(os.fwalk())`.

I understand that they have something to do with the hierarchy in which the files and directories are organised, but I don't quite get their exact meaning.

Also, the values change, depending on the integer assigned to dir_fd, and there is always one number missing (in this case `82`, see below).

Any ideas?

Code:

```
import os

os.chdir("/home/test")
inp = str(os.getcwd() + "/input")

l = list(os.fwalk(inp, dir_fd=3))
```

Output:

```
[('/home/test/input', ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d.txt'], 80),
 ('/home/test/input/a', ['aa'], ['ac.txt', 'ab.txt'], 81),
 ('/home/test/input/a/aa', [], [], 83),
 ('/home/test/input/b', [], ['bb.txt', 'bc.txt', 'ba.txt'], 81),
 ('/home/test/input/c', ['ca'], [], 81),
 ('/home/test/input/c/ca', ['caa'], ['cab.txt'], 83),
 ('/home/test/input/c/ca/caa', [], ['caaa.txt'], 84)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#files-and-directories) for `dir_fd` is confusingly located. Here's what it says:

> **paths relative to directory descriptors:** If *dir_fd* is not `None`, it should be a file descriptor referring to a directory, and the path to operate on should be relative; path will then be relative to that directory. If the path is absolute, *dir_fd* is ignored. (For POSIX systems, Python will call the variant of the function with an `at` suffix and possibly prefixed with `f` (e.g. call `faccessat` instead of `access`).
>
> You can check whether or not *dir_fd* is supported for a particular function on your platform using [`os.supports_dir_fd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.supports_dir_fd). If it’s unavailable, using it will raise a `NotImplementedError`.

So if you pass a `dir_fd`, then `fwalk` will interpret the path argument as relative to the directory specified by the file descriptor.

(It sounds like you also don't know what a file descriptor even is. A file descriptor is an integer identifying an open file or directory. You can get one with `os.open` or a few other ways. The advantage of using a file descriptor instead of a path here is that a file descriptor remains valid even if stuff gets moved around or renamed, invalidating old paths.)